# How do I display function arguments with PHP and the Whoops PrettyPageHandler error handler?

Tags: php, whoops

In Whoops, PlainTextHandler has the addTraceFunctionArgsToOutput method that I can use to display function arguments with the stack trace.  What is the equivalent for PrettyPageHandler?

In my live environment I do this to show function arguments in the error log:

```
$whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
$logger_to_error_log = new LoggerInterface();
$whoops_handler = new \Whoops\Handler\PlainTextHandler( $logger_to_error_log );
$whoops_handler->addTraceFunctionArgsToOutput( true );
$whoops->pushHandler( $whoops_handler );
```

$whoops->register();

This is what I have so far for my test environment, but PrettyPageHandler doesn't seem to have the addTraceFunctionArgsToOutput method:

```
$whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
$whoops_handler = new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler;
$whoops->pushHandler( $whoops_handler );
$whoops->register();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops requires the Symfony VarDumper for that functionality. I was able to go in with SSH, change to my public HTML directory and run

```
composer require symfony/var-dumper
```

After doing that, the arguments now appear on the error page.